# Paginate records

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, sql, ajax

I am generating records through PHP/SQL. The code displays 5 records. I'm trying to program so that when the next button is pressed, the next 5 records will show.

The code:

```
function show(qstring,qtype)
{
 $("#vsdiv").show();
 var myurl="scripts/searchpage.php"; 
 $.ajax({url: myurl, 
         dataType:'json',  
         data:{querystring:qstring,querytype:qtype},
         success: function(member)
         {
            $("#results").append('<tr class="me">'+'<th>#REC</th> <th>name</th><th>surname</th>');
            var j=0;
            var totrecs=1;
            for(var i=0;i<5;i++)
            {
                $("#results").append('<tr class="rows'+j+'">'+'
                                      <td class="ids" id="z'+i+'">'+totrecs+'</td>'+'
                                      <td>'+name[i].bdate+'</td>'+'
                                      <td class="users" id="username'+i+'">'+member[i].username+'</td>'+'
                                      <td id="contact'+i+'">'+member[i].fname+' '+member[i].lname+'</td>'+'
                                      <td><input type="checkbox" name="whome" id="showMe'+i+'"'+'
                                      class="boxes" onclick="getMe('+i+')" /></td></tr>');  
                totrecs++;
                j++;
            }
         }
       });
}
```

And for the HTML button:

```
<input type="button" id="next5" title="Next 5 Records" disabled="disabled" value="Next 5>>" />
```

Comment: please give details of your error/bug, otherwise you make the task of answering your question much bigger.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the `LIMIT` keyword. You can specify the records to start and end with like so:

```
blah sql statment blah LIMIT 1,5;
```

Your next query would be:

```
blah slq statement blah LIMIT 6,10;
```

If you want to be able to show all with only one query check out the JQuery library:

http://datatables.net/

Comment: i dont want to change the sql statement, just get the function for js?

Comment: You could look into the Jquery library datatable. See http://datatables.net/  I just used it in an app I finished and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

You can just store the return value from the ajax call in a javascript variable.  Then also store the starting position in the array for the next five records.

```
var returnedData = null;
var startingPos = 0;

function addFiveResults(){
  //Your code to append to results
  //from startingPos to startingPos + 5
  startingPos += 5;
}

$.ajax(...
success: function(member) {
    returnedData = member;
    startingPos = 0;
    addFiveResults();
});
```

Also make the onclick call addFiveResults();

This will reduce the number of ajax requests and is more versatile.  You could easily make the hard-coded 5 to be another variable that can be changed